# Is creating Google Play Console Developer Account,Scam?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am encountering persistent issues with the Google Play Console account verification process and seek assistance in resolving this matter.

Initially, I mistakenly provided incorrect information during the account creation process and subsequently rectified the error by submitting the appropriate and valid government document for verification. However, despite multiple attempts with accurate documentation, my account verification was repeatedly denied, leading to account restriction.

In a second attempt, my brother, with all valid proofs, encountered a similar issue. After submitting the necessary documents and paying the required $25 fee, the account was once again restricted, and despite reaching out via email, no refund was provided.

This situation has become highly inconvenient, and I am seeking guidance on how to rectify these issues promptly. I need a solution to successfully verify the account and proceed with publishing apps on the Google Play Store.

Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic